# How can we confirm the number of protons in an atom?

Tags: molecules, atoms, periodic-table, elements

The periodic table tells us that there are 6 protons in a carbon atom. Is there a way to verify this first-hand? Or are we just expected to believe it unquestioned?

Comment: Carbon is defined as an atom with six protons (and 6 electrons). That is the nature of the periodic table. It is so per definition. I suppose your real question is: how can we determine if something is really carbon. Right?

Comment: My real question would be 'how do we really know that what they've been telling us in school about atomic structure is true?'

Comment: That what about the atomic structure is true? The atomic structure is a model. It is not known if it represents reality completely (probably not). This can never be known.

Comment: @Jori then why claim that carbon has x protons as if it were the truth ?

Comment: Excellent question : what has been affirmed without proof can also be denied without proof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) While not easy, it is possible to obtain mass-spectrum of full range of ions, including fully ionized. By number of peaks with Z/E corresponding as X, X/2, X/3 ... X/n it is possible to ensure that an element has exactly n electrons and protons. It is still difficult to ensure full ionization of heavier atoms, so the method is not applicable for heavier elements. This, however, is the only direct method I can think of. Should work for carbon, though.

2) Various X-ray-derived spectral methods. While not providing direct evidence, they do provide information on electronic shell structure, that can be compared with theoretical calculations.

Comment: I'm still not convinced